# How to check if a X509 certificate is in the trusted store

Tags: c, openssl

I am trying to validate a certificate chain using openssl library for C.
I know that it can be done automatically using other function calls, but I am doing this to understand how these things actually work.

I am currently validating **each certificate in the certificate chain.**

I have managed to verify the intermediate certificates (non-root), but I can't find any documentation to validate the root certificate.

Specifically, I would like to be able to reject invalid SSL certificates like `untrusted-root.badssl.com` or `self-signed.badssl.com`.

I have set up the trusted certificate store on my system, so my idea was the following: I must check that the last certificate in the chain is in the trusted store.

How am I supposed to do this?

I currently have the following code.

```c
X509* cert; // contains the last certificate in the certificate chain

// the trusted certificate store on my system
X509_STORE* store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(ctx);
```

I have tried calling `X509_trusted`, `X509_check_trust` but they don't seem to reject the invalid certificates mentioned above. (I might be doing something wrong)

`X509_self_signed` does not reject the invalid certificates, since the signature is still valid.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.